# Iterating through makefile argument list

Tags: makefile, system-verilog, uvm, test-bench

I want my makefile to parse each arg=value pair in the $(cfg) list below. And then use these $(arg) and $(value) in the makefile. These arg=value pair can be separated by space or comma.

Example: I want to override three test variables (A, B, C) through command line

```
make run test=my_test.sv cfg="A=3, B=4, C=5"
```

Makefile should do something like this:

```
foreach $arg,$val in $cfg  ----> +uvm_set_config_int=*,$arg,$val
```

Effective result:

```
+uvm_set_config_int=*,A,3
+uvm_set_config_int=*,B,4
+uvm_set_config_int=*,C,5
```

My purpose above is to allow overriding of any default test configuration through command line.

I checked [Variable arguments list to a Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962297/variable-arguments-list-to-a-makefile), [Passing arguments to "make run"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214575/passing-arguments-to-make-run) however it did not answer my specific question.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Why don't you use `make ... A=3 B=4 C=5`? Or the variable names (`A`, `B`, `C`) can be anything?

Comment: variable names can be anything. Solution by Madscientist solves my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't be right:

```
+uvm_set_config_int=*,A,3
+uvm_set_config_int=*,B,4
+uvm_set_config_int=*,C,5
```

because that just sets, then overrides, the single value `+uvm_set_config_int`.  At the end the variable `+uvm_set_config_int` will contain the single value `*,C,5` since that's the last assignment.  Maybe you mean to use `uvm_set_config_int += ...` in each of the above, to append to the existing value?

I really don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here.

However, here's an example of how to do what you've asked, even though it doesn't seem to make much sense:

```
c = ,
$(foreach X,$(subst $c, ,$(cfg)),$(eval +uvm_set_config_int=*,$(subst =,$c,$X)))
```

Since commas are special to make functions we have to hide them behind a variable `$c` above.  The first `subst` turns commas into spaces, since that's what make uses to delimit words.  The second converts `=` to comma so you can change `A=3` to `A,3` etc.  The `eval` evaluates the text given as a makefile line.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are doing some form of build configuration through make, you can use [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) which is a library with functionality supporting this task. In gmtt you can formulate your task like this:

```
include gmtt/gmtt.mk

cfg-table := 2 $(cfg) # make a gmtt-table from the variable

# now select column 1 and 2 from the table for the right test and format the output (without the need to format, just use "select")
smoketest-cfg := $(call map-select,1 2,$(cfg-table),$$(call glob-match,$$1,smoketest*),+uvm_set_config=*$(comma)$$1$(comma)$$2)

regressiontest-cfg := $(call map-select,1 2,$(cfg-table),$$(call glob-match,$$1,regressiontest*),+uvm_set_config=*$(comma)$$1$(comma)$$2)


$(info $(smoketest-cfg))
$(info $(regressiontest-cfg))
$(info -----------------------)
$(info $(subst $(space),$(newline),$(strip $(smoketest-cfg))))
```

and you should now be able to call it like:

```
make cfg="smoketest-A 1 smoketest-B 2 regressiontest-A 3 regressiontest-B 4"
```

(gmtt uses tables which are just GNUmake lists, therefore you must use spaces as separators of the items and you must not have empty "cells".)

Output:

```
 +uvm_set_config=*,smoketest-A,1 +uvm_set_config=*,smoketest-B,2
 +uvm_set_config=*,regressiontest-A,3 +uvm_set_config=*,regressiontest-B,4
-----------------------
+uvm_set_config=*,smoketest-A,1
+uvm_set_config=*,smoketest-B,2
```

Note that you need to quote `,` in your output format as `$(comma)` (a variable provided by gmtt) because of the generous character handling of make which takes nearly everything as a function parameter, even `\`, which therefore doesn't help as escaping character.